# Need help on mock data generator using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to generate mock data using this online framework - https://github.com/danibram/mocker-data-generator

I would like to mock an array of elements which is repetitive in my existing JSON element.

**This is my code:**

```
var user = {
    year: {
        chance: 'guid'
    },
    age: {
        faker: 'name.findName'
    },
    email: {
        faker: 'internet.email'
    }
};
var house = {
    mateIds: {
        hasMany: 'test',
        max: 5,
        min: 1,
    }
};

mocker()
    .schema('test', user, 1)
    .schema('houses', house, 1)
```

Use this online editor to get the output: https://danibram.github.io/mocker-data-generator/#unique

But I'm expecting output like below: In my actual output, I'm getting a **test** array element which I want to get rid of from my output.

```
{
    "houses": [{
        "mateIds": [{
                "year": "155f7b10-4c60-5dfd-8a71-9e4a9a081ea4",
                "age": "Sheridan O'Reilly",
                "email": "Rebekah69@hotmail.com"
            },
            {
                "year": "155f7b10-4c60-5dfd-8a71-9e4a9a081ea4",
                "age": "Sheridan O'Reilly",
                "email": "Rebekah69@hotmail.com"
            },
            {
                "year": "155f7b10-4c60-5dfd-8a71-9e4a9a081ea4",
                "age": "Sheridan O'Reilly",
                "email": "Rebekah69@hotmail.com"
            },
            {
                "year": "155f7b10-4c60-5dfd-8a71-9e4a9a081ea4",
                "age": "Sheridan O'Reilly",
                "email": "Rebekah69@hotmail.com"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a limitation of the tool. In order to reference the user in the house, the user needs to be generated. So your output will therefore generate the test array containing the user as well.

You can try using the .build() pipe to filter out the unwanted data, and return only the data.houses.

The syntax would be:

```
mocker()
    .schema('test', user,  1)
    .schema('houses', house, 1)
    .build(function(err, data){
        return data.houses
    })
```